# How to generate a "front" or "introduction" page for PHPDocumentor

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

The default front page for a project documented using PHPDocumentor seems to be just labelled "Documentation". I'd like to put some sort of project overview page either as the front page or in there somewhere.

Is there a recommended way of doing this?